# Pull-to-Refresh is jumpy

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, pull-to-refresh

I'm looking to implement a Pull-to-refresh, and I'm seeing that the pull-to-refresh action isn't smooth; it makes the Content View jump around the screen, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSms4.jpg

I have the following constraints:

[image: Constraints]

My ViewController looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadData), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

        scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }

    @objc func reloadData() {
        textLabel.text = "SURPRISE"
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```